How to determine start of week for a given locale in Apex
My biggest complaint about SF is there are some many places where functionality is wired to the current User's identity when I have to do something in Apex on behalf of a user other than the currently-running User.
I need to determine based on the locale of a User other than the running User whether the start of the week is Sunday or Monday.  Many of the Date and Datetime methods work specifically for the running User or maybe before GMT but not for an arbitrary user or timezone.
The code below works based on the running user --
    public Boolean startOfWeekIsSunday() {
        Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2024,9,1);
        Date myStartOfWeek = myDate.toStartOfWeek();
        return myDate == myStartOfWeek;
    }

What I need is --
    public Boolean startOfWeekIsSunday(String localeSidKey) {
        /// TBD
    }

Any ideas?

I kinda hesitate to suggest it, because it kinda makes my skin crawl, but you could use the JWT flow to make a callout from your org, into that same org. The JWT flow (when you have "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" in your connected app) would effectively give you "execute this code as specific user X".

It's for a managed package so doing callout backs to the org are all sorts of security concerns.

This isn't a solution to getting the start of day for any locale real time.  It's a work around.  I've written some ad-hoc code to get the start of week for each locale.  From that, I can hard-code a list for the days / locales I need.
First, I learned if you change the locale of a User, the change in behavior will not occur in the same request.  So I had to use a batch and a batchsize of 1 and get the day for the locale on the next iteration.  Throw away code to get the data below...
global class KKIterateLocaleSidKeyBatch implements Database.Batchable<String>, Iterator<String>, Iterable<String>, Database.Stateful {

    /*
    KKIterateLocaleSidKeyBatch batcher = new KKIterateLocaleSidKeyBatch();
    Database.executeBatch(batcher, 1);
    */

    // Logging variables
    list<String> userLocaleList;
    list<String> newLocaleList;
    map<Integer,list<String>>offsetLocaleMap;

    // Iterator variables
    private Integer currentIndex;
    private List<String> picklistValueList;

    // Constructor
    global KKIterateLocaleSidKeyBatch() {
        // Initialize iterator variables
        currentIndex = -1;
        picklistValueList = getLocaleSidKeypicklistValueList();
        userLocaleList = new list<String> ();
        newLocaleList = new list<String> ();
        offsetLocaleMap = new map<Integer,list<String>>();
    }

    // Start method
    global Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return this;
    }

    // Execute method
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<String> scope) {
        // Process each value in the batch
        for(String value : scope) {
            doIt(value);
        }
    }

    // Finish method
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        logIt();
        System.debug('userLocaleList -- \n' + JSON.serialize(userLocaleList) + '\n' );
        System.debug('newLocaleList -- \n'  + JSON.serialize(newLocaleList) + '\n' );
        System.debug('offsetLocaleMap -- \n'  + JSON.serialize(offsetLocaleMap) + '\n' );
    }

    // Iterator methods
    global Boolean hasNext() {
        return currentIndex < picklistValueList.size() - 1;
    }

    global String next() {
        currentIndex++;
        return picklistValueList[currentIndex];
    }

    // Iterable method
    global Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return this;
    }

    // Method to fetch picklist values for LocaleSidKey
    private List<String> getLocaleSidKeypicklistValueList() {
        List<String> picklistValueList = new List<String>();
        list<Schema.PicklistEntry>rawPicklist = User.localeSidKey.getDescribe().getpicklistValues();
        Integer counter = 0;
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry pickIter : rawPicklist) {
            String locale = pickIter.getValue();
            picklistValueList.add(locale);
        }
        return picklistValueList;
    }

    private void doIt(String locale) {
        logIt();
        userLocaleList.add(UserInfo.getLocale());
        newLocaleList.add(locale);
        User sfUser = new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), localeSidKey = locale);
        update sfUser;       
    }

    private void logIt() {
        String locale = UserInfo.getLocale();
        Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2024,9,1);
        Date myStartOfWeek = myDate.toStartOfWeek();
        Integer diff = myDate.daysBetween(myStartOfWeek);
        list<String>localeList = offsetLocaleMap.get(diff);
        if (localeList == null) {
            offsetLocaleMap.put(diff,new list<String>{locale});
        } else {
            localeList.add(locale);
        }
    }
}

Now I have the data below.  From that I can hard-code a class to get start of week by locale.
//Saturday--
{"-1":["ar","ar_DZ","ar_BH","ar_EG","ar_IQ","ar_JO","ar_KW","ar_LY","ar_OM","ar_QA","ar_AE","en_AE","ps_AF","fa","so_DJ"],
//Monday--
"-6":["sq","sq_AL","ar_LB","ar_MA","ar_TN","hy","hy_AM","az_AZ","eu","eu_ES","be_BY","bs","bs_BA","bg","bg_BG","ca","ca_ES_EURO","ca_ES","zh_MY","hr","hr_HR","cs","cs_CZ","da","da_DK","nl","nl_AW","nl_BE","nl_NL","nl_SR","en_AU","en_BB","en_BE","en_BM","en_CM","en_KY","en_CY","en_ER","en_SZ","en_FK","en_FJ","en_GM","en_DE","en_GH","en_GI","en_GY","en_IE_EURO","en_IE","en_LR","en_MG","en_MW","en_MY","en_MU","en_NA","en_NL","en_NZ","en_NG","en_PG","en_RW","en_SC","en_SL","en_SX","en_SB","en_SH","en_TZ","en_TO","en_UG","en_GB","en_VU","et","et_EE","fi","fi_FI_EURO","fi_FI","fr","fr_BE","fr_KM","fr_FR_EURO","fr_FR","fr_GN","fr_HT","fr_LU","fr_MR","fr_MC","fr_MA","fr_CH","fr_WF","ka","ka_GE","de","de_AT_EURO","de_AT","de_BE","de_DE_EURO","de_DE","de_LU_EURO","de_LU","de_CH","el","el_CY","el_GR","ht","ht_HT","hmn","hu","hu_HU","is","is_IS","ga","ga_IE","it","it_IT","it_CH","kl","kl_GL","kk","kk_KZ","ky_KG","lv","lv_LV","lt","lt_LT","lu_CD","lb","lb_LU","mk","mk_MK","ms","ms_BN","ms_MY","sh_ME","no","no_NO","pl","pl_PL","pt_AO","pt_CV","pt_ST","ro","ro_MD","ro_RO","rm","rm_CH","rn_BI","ru","ru_AM","ru_BY","ru_KZ","ru_KG","ru_LT","ru_MD","ru_PL","ru_RU","ru_UA","sr","sr_BA","sr_CS","sh","sh_BA","sh_CS","sr_RS","sk","sk_SK","sl","sl_SI","so_SO","es","es_AR","es_BO","es_CL","es_CR","es_EC","es_ES_EURO","es_ES","es_UY","sw","sv","sv_SE","tg_TJ","ta_LK","mi","mi_NZ","th_TH","tr","tr_TR","uk","uk_UA","uz_LATN_UZ","vi","vi_VN","cy","cy_GB","ji","yo_BJ"],
//Sunday--
"0":["zu_ZA","af","af_ZA","am","am_ET","ar_SA","ar_YE","bn","bn_BD","bn_IN","my","my_MM","zh","zh_CN_PINYIN","zh_CN_STROKE","zh_CN","zh_HK_STROKE","zh_HK","zh_MO","zh_SG","zh_TW_STROKE","zh_TW","dz_BT","en_AG","en_BS","en_BZ","en_BW","en_CA","en_HK","en_IN","en_ID","en_IL","en_JM","en_KE","en_MT","en_PK","en_PH","en_WS","en_SG","en_ZA","en_TT","en_US","fr_CA","gu","gu_IN","ht_US","haw","haw_US","iw","iw_IL","hi","hi_IN","hmn_US","in","in_ID","ja","ja_JP","kn","kn_IN","km","km_KH","ko","ko_KR","lo_LA","ml","ml_IN","mt","mt_MT","mr","mr_IN","ne_NP","pt","pt_BR","pt_MZ","pt_PT","pa","pa_IN","sm","sm_WS","sm_US","es_CO","es_DO","es_SV","es_GT","es_HN","es_MX","es_NI","es_PA","es_PY","es_PE","es_PR","es_US","es_VE","sw_KE","tl","tl_PH","ta","ta_IN","te","te_IN","th","ti_ET","ur","ur_PK","xh","xh_ZA","ji_US","zu","zu_ZA"]}

excellent work here -- and probably pretty stable until the next French Revolution that introduces a 10 day week :-)
